# how to fix ''nothing to repeat at position 2''

Tags: python, regex, stemming, lemmatization

ı am trying to stemmize words in tex of dataframe

data is a dataframe , karma is text column , zargan is the dict of word and root of word

```
for a in range(1,100000):
    for j in data.KARMA[a].split():
        pattern = r'\b'+j+r'\b' 
        data.KARMA[a] = re.sub(pattern, str(zargan.get(j,j)),data.KARMA[a]) 
print(data.KARMA[1])
```

I want to change the word and root in the texts

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `j` contains some regular expression special character like `*`. If you want it to be interpreted as literal text, you can say

```
    pattern = r'\b'+re.escape(j)+r'\b'
```

and possibly the same for `r` if it should similarly be coerced into a literal string.